The "one block roughly every 10 min" does not match the median time stamp of consecutive blocks
When I check the time or mediantime fields recorded in bitcoin blocks, the delta between consecutive blocks is rarely the commonly known 10 min interval.
For instance,
Block   Median Time     Delta
------  -----------     -----
299996  1399700280
299997  1399700940      660
299998  1399700975      35
299999  1399701277      302
300000  1399701278      1

I am looking for references diving deep into mathematical proof of the differences.

This question is similar to: Why can the block production rate be as low as two per hour?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are a few similar topics on this site already, e.g., Why was the time between these two blocks not approximately 10 minutes?, What keeps the average block time at 10 minutes?, and What is the expected time until the next block is found?. Does any of these answer your question? If not, could you please clarify how your question is different?

The time between two blocks, assuming the hashrate and difficulty match, follows an exponential distribution with mean 10 minutes.
The distribution has:

a mean of 10 minutes (600 seconds)
a median of 6 minutes and 56 seconds (600/ln(2) seconds).

The difference between the two is due to the long tail the distribution has: while 50% of blocks will be shorter than ~7 minutes, and 50% will be longer, the longer ones are spread out over a much larger range (up to infinity, even), driving the average up.

Thank you! Could you please point me to any resource explaining the details of the exponential distribution with a mean of 10? I am mainly looking for mathematical proof to know if there is a mathematical basis or if it is primarily based on an accepted consensus.

This is trivial to prove, and can readily be computed: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=median+of+exponential+distribution+with+lambda%3D1%2F600 ?

That makes sense! Thanks! I wonder if there are any sources explaining why we think it follows the exponential/Poisson distribution. I found quite a few posts about how those distributions work, but it is unclear why we believe it follows those distributions.

It is a Poisson process (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process), which follows from the fact that every hashing attempt is independent. The time between events in a Poisson process is exponentially distributed.

Is there any reference for "The time between events in a Poisson process is exponentially distributed"?
